# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) even with async call inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous

I've been fighting with this all day guys.
[image]

I've read a ton of SO questions where this was the problem and most of them were solved moving the conflicting piece of code inside the useEffect hook, however this hasn't solved the issue.

```
const UnsignedDocuments = (props) => {
const [docsWithInfo, setDocsWithInfo] = useState({arr: []})
const userController = new UserController()
const getDocInfo = async () => {
    const tmp = [];
    for (const index in props.unsignedDocuments) {
        const newDoc = await userController.getSignDocData(props.unsignedDocuments[index].multilateralId)
        if (newDoc) {
            tmp.push(newDoc)
            console.log(tmp)
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
useEffect(() => {
    const getInfo = async () => {

       const temp = await Promise.all([getDocInfo()]).then(res=>setDocsWithInfo({arr: res}));

        console.log(temp, typeof temp)
    }
    getInfo();

}, []);

async getSignDocData(multilateralId) {
    const snapshot = await Promise.resolve(this.signDocCollection.where('multilateralId', '==', multilateralId).get())
    if (snapshot.size > 0) {
        return snapshot.docs[0].data();
    }
}
```

EDIT: added return

```
return (
    <Accordion bsPrefix='seguridata' style={{'position': 'inherit'}}>
        <Accordion.Header>Por Firmar <Badge style={{'marginLeft': '2rem'}}
                                            bg="dark">x</Badge></Accordion.Header>
        <Accordion.Body>
            <Accordion flush><SignItem key={1} docsWithInfo={docsWithInfo.arr}/></Accordion>

        </Accordion.Body>

    </Accordion>
)
```

}

EDIT 2 :
Changed temp to

```
       const temp = await Promise.all([getDocInfo()]).then(res =>setDocsWithInfo({arr: res}));
```

But I still have the same error

Comment: is this code valid? there is no `return` piece, please provide it

Comment: @EugeneMikhushkin It is valid. I added the return. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `.then` before set state:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getInfo = async () => {
        const temp = await Promise.all([getDocInfo()])
                                  .then(res => setDocsWithInfo({arr: res})
        console.log(temp, typeof temp)
    }
    getInfo();

}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) return an array of promises, so be aware of that. You need to chain it with

```
Promise.all([...]).then(([...])=>{
})
```

Otherwise you need to make many `await` statements.

```
async f = () => {
  await fetch1()
  await fetch2()
  // etc
}
```

What I want to say, you need to parse in correct way `docsWithInfo` variable, it contains an array of unresolved promises. That causes an error.

Edit: one more thing to clarify. React indeed accepts as a child only a string or JSX. Of you are trying something like

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      arr: results
    }
    {[1,2,3]}
  </div>
)
```

this will throw an error, same with other data types, arrays too. So make sure you are passing to `return` statement a string or JSX, not any other data types.

Comment: Can you please provide `getSignDocData` in your question

Comment: @CrappyCoder try `const temp = await Promise.all([getDocInfo()]).then(res=>setDocsWithInfo({arr: res.toString()}));`

Comment: @EugeneMikhushkin that fixes it! What's the meaning of this? Why can't I pass an array?

Comment: @CrappyCoder made an edit with an explanation of answer. If I helped you please vote.

Comment: @EugeneMikhushkin maybe I didn't explained myself correctly, I'm trying to pass the array as a prop to another component

Comment: read between the lines - you passed it but did not render correct. You passed a prop as [] and <SignItem /> has somewhere in `return` or `render` same behavior {props.docsWithInfo.arr}. You need to loop through an array with `map`.  It is basics of React. Check regarding docs. 

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: `{props.docsWithInfo.arr.map((doc) => doc)}`